# How to clip a part of angular view and represent it

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

I want to create a TabComponent in Angular 8 in a library. So I want the end-user to use my component like this:

```
<tab-view>
    <tab-pane>
        <tab-title>
            <h1>Tab 1</h1>
        </tab-title>
        My Tab 1 Content
    </tab-pane>
    <tab-pane>
        <tab-title>
            <h1>Tab 2</h1>
        </tab-title>
        My Tab 2 Content
    </tab-pane>
</tab-view>
```

and inside my `<tab-view>` component, I've a code like this:

```
<div class="tab-view">
    <div class="tab-view-pills">
        <!-- I wan't my tab titles appear here -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab-view-panes">
        <!-- I wan't my contents appear here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

the question is, how can I represent my tab pills and content in the place I've written above?

Is there any way to use `<ng-content>` in commented places?

Workgaround: I've studied [this solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example) but it's not what I want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `select` attribute on `<ng-content>` to differentiate the elements on projection. It should work like this:

```
<div class="tab-view">
  <div class="tab-view-pills">
    <ng-content select="tab-title"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-view-panes">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

The key here is that `<ng-content>` accepts a `select` attribute that allows you to control which elements are rendered and where. The argument to `select` is a css selector for the elements you want to render. For example it can be a class `select=".myClass"` an attribute `select="[myAttr]"` or a tag `select="span"`. If you don't provide a `select` attribute `ng-content` will render everything else that hasn't been selected with a `select` attribute. So for example in the code above `<ng-content select="tab-title"></ng-content>` will render only `<tab-title>` inside that `ng-content` and `<ng-content></ng-content>` the rest of the content except `<tab-title>` which had already been selected. [here](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b) is a good article that explains this further.

Comment: Yes but what if I would like to take a full control over pills. I don't want to just copy user code to my tab header.

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab I updated my answer above. Hope it helps.